# Odd => operator usage

Tags: c#, lambda

I am well aware about the "=>" being the lambda operator in c# and have used it a lot so far.

But today I stumbled upon a new way (for me, at least) of using this operator that I can't get my head around:

```
public abstract class Connection : IConnection
{
     protected HttpClient HttpClient { get; private set; }

     ...    

     public Uri Address => HttpClient.BaseAddress;

     public TimeSpan Timeout => HttpClient.Timeout;

     ...

}
```

I've checked [=> Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx) and [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) but couldn't find any mention for this type of usage.

The code is from the [MyCouch project on GitHub](https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch) in [this](https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch/blob/master/source/projects/MyCouch/Net/Connection.cs) source file.

What am I missing?

Comment: thats expression bodied method. a method returns what is after =>

Comment: C# 6.0's new feature.